# How to provide status updates to asp.net page from long running WCF service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, asp.net-4.0

I have an asp.net 4 site. My client wants to go to a page and run a process which updates data from their accounting app into his site. This process can take a couple hours. I wanted to implement a WCF service hosted from Windows service. I'm finding info on how this works but my client also wants status updates from this service as it runs. My question is how can you implement this with a WCF service? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asp.net website and the wcf service can share a database (SQL Server or a no-sql), from wcf you'll insert status updates and from asp.net you'll display them.